# Matlab prettifier problem with *

Tags: miktex, lstlisting, matlab-prettifier

I'm trying to use the matlab-prettifier. Following code does not compile:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[
style      = Matlab-editor,
basicstyle = \mlttfamily,
]
ro=zeros(length(prec),length(prec)+length(h)-1);
for i=t
    ro(i,i:i+length(h)-1)=prec(i) * h;
end 
runoff = sum(ro,1);
\end{lstlisting}
```

As soon as I remove the *, it works.
Also if I just use the lstlisting environment without

```
[
    style      = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle = \mlttfamily,
    ]
```

and put the * back in, everything works fine.
I followed the official documentation: https://github.com/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier/wiki
Is there a bug in the matlab-prettifier, or am I doing sth wrong?

*EDIT:
Following you will find a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[
    style      = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle = \mlttfamily,
    ]
    ro=zeros(length(prec),length(prec)+length(h)-1);
    for i=t
    ro(i,i:i+length(h)-1)=prec(i) * h;
    end 
    runoff = sum(ro,1);
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is the output of Texstudio:

```
Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "matlabprettifier".tex

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.l

og

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

*EDIT2
Following, you will find the output of makepk and makemf:

makepk:

> 2019-04-06 17:25:23,589+0200 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with
>   command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose fvmr8r 510
>   600 0+510/600 2019-04-06 17:25:23,592+0200 INFO  makepk - Trying to
>   make PK font fvmr8r at 510 DPI... 2019-04-06 17:25:23,604+0200 INFO 
>   makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour 2019-04-06 17:25:23,614+0200
>   INFO  makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe... 2019-04-06
>   17:25:23,614+0200 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe
>   --miktex-enable-installer --verbose fvmr8r 2019-04-06 17:25:23,956+0200 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
>   2019-04-06 17:25:23,957+0200 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe
>   --miktex-enable-installer -q -t fvmr8r 2019-04-06 17:25:24,507+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font fvmr8r could not be created. 2019-04-06
>   17:25:24,507+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font fvmr8r could not be
>   created. 2019-04-06 17:25:24,507+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
>   2019-04-06 17:25:24,507+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source:  2019-04-06
>   17:25:24,507+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0

makemf:

> 2019-04-06 17:25:23,888+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with
>   command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --verbose
>   fvmr8r 2019-04-06 17:25:23,899+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The fvmr8r
>   source file could not be found. 2019-04-06 17:25:23,899+0200 FATAL
>   miktex-makemf - The fvmr8r source file could not be found. 2019-04-06
>   17:25:23,899+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info:  2019-04-06
>   17:25:23,899+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source:  2019-04-06
>   17:25:23,899+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0

Comment: Could you please make a [MWE (minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe. Adding the error message to your question could also be helpful.  If I use your code and add a documentclass as well as the relevant packages your code compiles just fine.

Comment: ok, one moment, I will add it as an edit

Comment: sorry I already edited it, didn't notice your comment. The document runs without error when I try it.

Comment: ok, I will also add the error logs of makemf and makepk, maybe you or someone else can find something

Comment: so it is not directly related to the matlab code at all, you simply don't have tha bera fonts installed, in texlive I get `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bera/fvmr8r.tfm` not sure how to update miktex to have the fonts

Comment: Ok, so I found out, that acutally the font Bera (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/bera/) is missing.
Went into MiKTeX, uninstalled, reinstalled and refreshed the databases but it didn't help

Comment: Just had a look at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/bera/ 
there is a file fvmr8a but no fvmr8r
what's going on here? and why is it working for @DavidCarlisle ?

Comment: Ok, apparently the fvmr8r is part of the TeX support files from the archive bera.zip.
apparently, I'm missing these.
How can I get them?
Windows 10/ Miktex/ Texstudio

Comment: apparently my Miktex package manager won't install the additional support files.
I tried to unpack them, put them in a new directory and added this as a TEXMF directory as stated in the documentation of Bera, but it does not work.